# When to 401 vs when to 302

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, httpresponse, functional-testing, http-response-codes

I am working on a Rails REST-based website and am writing my functional tests for the controllers. As a REST based application, I am making use of several HTTP verbs, `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` etc.

I've noticed that I am inconsistent in my application of 401 and 302 HTTP response codes regarding anonymous users. Sometimes when they make a request for a resource that requires authentication, I return 401 Unauthorized. Other times, I return 302 and redirect them to a login page.

Is there standard that I should be following here? When should 401s be used? When should I redirect to a login page? For example,

- Should `GETs` be redirected?
- Should `POSTs` get a `401`?
- What do I do for AJAX requests where a 302 wouldnt be followed?

Or perhaps this is all just matter of opinion, a convention that I need choose and enforce on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I read the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), unauthenticated users requesting a resource which requires authentication should consistently receive a `401 Unauthorized`. From the RFC:

`302 Found`: The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI.

`401 Unauthorized`: The request requires user authentication.

Clearly the `302` does not correctly describe your situation and the `401` does.

Comment: Yes. Strictly speaking that is correct. However, it is not practical. I'm sure most people on SO are aware that it is a common practice for websites to redirect users to a log in page when they try to access a protected resource. This is exactly what I want to do with my site. Simply saying, "Nope, not authorized" is not a suitable situation for me. Nor do I want search engines crawling my entire site and seeing log in forms on every URL.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking the question if you've already decided on the answer. Regardless, doing *something* consistently is much better than returning 401 in some situations and 302 in others.

Comment: I haven't decided on an answer. It sounds like you are making some connections that I have not. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: I just edited the question. Perhaps the update will clarify where I am looking for help.

Comment: The AJAX redirect on 302 issue is why you should be using 401 consistently. If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to return 302 sometimes and 401 other times. That's worse than returning 302 always - clients have to write error handling logic that treats different kinds of requests differently, and they have to remember whatever choices you've made instead of following the established convention. If you want a redirect, build it into the client side when a request comes back with a 401. You used the REST tag, so I gave a REST answer. You can, of course do whatever you want!

Comment: Good point. I guess I'm not looking for a pure REST point of view. I think I need to take a step back and maybe do a little redeisgn.

Comment: This just got a "popular question" badge so I thought I might come back and let you know that you sold me on this. No 302s. Do 401s correctly and let the client figure out what to do. REST is REST. Dont screw with it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if search engines will index a 401 page.

Ideally, for a restricted page for users who are not authenticated:
401 status code and show the sign in form.

For authenticated users who are still not allowed:
403 and "Not Authorized" page.

For the sign in page:
200 OK and show the sign in form.